# Flutter Firebase in-app messaging not working on publish

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-in-app-messaging

I'm using `firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.2.3` on my application.

I can test my Firebase In-app messaging campaign on a real device, but when I published my campaign nothing seems to work.

[image]

I'm using the default on_foreground trigger event and another custom event. When I close my app and open it again nothing appears.

[image]

Does it take some time to start working? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by re-installing my application.

I assume the campaign didn't appear because I was already **testing** the campaign, and it's frequency was *Once per device*.

[image]

But still an in-app messaging test should not be considered as a real campaign engagement. It may be Firebase inner bug.

Hope this will help someone out there...